# Using Vue components in a mixed ES/TS project

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I want to be able to use Vue files for both JavaScript and TypeScript, so in the `<script>` tag when `lang` is not set or set to `js` then use ES2015 and when `<script lang="ts">` use TypeScript. I have an existing vue+ts project, now we decided that we want to build the app on top of [vue-paper-dashboard](https://github.com/cristijora/vue-paper-dashboard/#vue-paper-dashboard--) that is written in ES6. I still want to keep my components in TS and `.vue` files with `<script lang="ts">`. So started with empty dashboard project and replaced Babel/ESLint with TS/TSLint. Project still loads fine: [vue-paper-dashboard-typescript](https://github.com/omidkrad/vue-paper-dashboard-typescript), however, when in any `.vue` file I set `<script lang="ts">` I get errors like:

```
Module build failed: Error: Could not find file: 'src/components/Dashboard/Views/Overview.vue'.
```

I've already set `--allowJs` compiler option to true. I also tried changing entry file from `main.js` to `main.ts`, used `entryFileIsJs: true` for ts-loader, to no avail. How can I get vue single file components work in a mixed ES/TS project?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the fix. For some reason it worked the second time I tried to change the entry point from `main.js` to `main.ts` and making necessary fixes in the ts file to compile.

I have a working sample here: [vue-paper-dashboard-typescript](https://github.com/omidkrad/vue-paper-dashboard-typescript)

---

**Update:** Creative-Tim is now providing [Vue Paper Dashboard 2 Pro](https://www.creative-tim.com/product/vue-paper-dashboard-2-pro) (not free) which uses CLI 3 that supports TypeScript. Add TS support to the project with this command: `vue add @vue/typescript`.